# Chisel: Resolvers Key in build.sbt

Tags: sbt, chisel

Although it's a fundamental question, what resolver key do in build.sbt. I have just started learning chisel3
for example.

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
           Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
           Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
         )
```

If you suggest any link to read the build.sbt for chisel projects or in general. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolvers tell sbt where to look for things specified in libraryDependencies.
Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots") is a predefined repository at Sonatype OSS Maven, under the "snapshots" directory.
Google 'sbt Resolvers' and you will find plenty of information.
For example the manual at [Resolvers Page at SBT documentation site](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html)